# initialization lists in copy constructor

Tags: c++, struct

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A{
    A(){}
    A(const A&) {cout<<"1";}
};

struct B: A{
    B(){}
    B(const B&){}
};

struct C: A{
    C(){}
    C(const B&rhs):A(rhs){} 
};

struct D:A{
    D(){}
};

int main(){
    D d;
    D dcopy(d);
    C c;
    C ccopy(c);
    B b;
    B bcopy(b);
    }
```

when I run this program I have expected output as: 111, but it is giving output as:11, please explain !!!

```
C(const B& rhs) : A(rhs) {}  // presence of this line has no influence on output,
                             // please explain, why?
```

Comment: It would help a lot if you explained why you expect "111" as the output or why you would expect the `C(const B&)` constructor to make any difference.

Comment: Try enabling warnings and paying attention to them. I got this warning in your code: `testCopyCtor.cpp: In copy constructor ‘B::B(const B&)’:
testCopyCtor.cpp:11:5: error: base class ‘struct A’ should be explicitly initialized in the copy constructor [-Werror=extra]
     B(const B&){}
     ^
`

Comment: @David, when dcopy,ccopy & bcopy is called each time copy constructor A should be called as it is inherited to these structures. /so I have expected op as 111.

Comment: @vidya Good. I guessed right. See my answer.

Comment: Note that your `C(const B& rhs)` is NOT a copy constructor. It is never called.

Comment: is it should be like this  C(const C&rhs):A(rhs){} ?

Comment: @vidya: Yes, that would make it a copy constructor.

Comment: whether copy constructor present or not in struct B or struct C the output is 111, then when these copy constructor's will be useful?

Comment: @vidya: Your copy constructors are trivial, so they really don't do anything different from the compiler-provided defaults. Copy constructors are useful in some situations, such as in classes that contain pointer or reference members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
B(const B&){}
```

This code doesn't output anything, nor does it copy-construct the `A` (it default constructs it). So `B bcopy(b)` doesn't output anything. Perhaps you meant:

```
B(const B& rhs) : A(rhs) {}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what the warning in my comment was hinting at.

Answer (score 0):

According to the C++ Standard

> 8 In a non-delegating constructor, if a given non-static data member
>   or base class is not designated by a mem-initializer-id (including the
>   case where there is no mem-initializer-list because the constructor
>   has no ctor-initializer) and the entity is not a virtual base class of
>   an abstract class (10.4), then ...
>
> **— otherwise, the entity is default-initialized (8.5).**

And

> 15 The implicitly-defined copy/move constructor for a non-union class
>   X performs a memberwise copy/move of its bases and members.

So in your example class D has implicitly defined copy constructor and according to the second quote it performs coping of its base class that is it calls the copy constructor of A.

The same is valid for class C (C has no explicitly user-defined copy constructor, so the compiler defines an implicit copy constructor. This definition C(const B& rhs) : A(rhs) {}   is not a definition of the copy constructor. It is a constructor with one parameter).

Class B has no implicitly defined copy constructor. It has a user-defined copy constructor. So according to the first quote it performs default initialization of its subobjects that is it calls the default constructor of class A.